# Bridging headers importing framework into viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, amazon-web-services, header-files

I am new to IOS coding and I am trying to use the AWS SDK which is written in objective C.

After trying all day to get the SDK working for a simple table scan in with swift, I am now trying just use objective C.

I set it up using the AWS Mobile manager which already has the headers and framework in the project

[image]

So I am working in my RateSongsViewController.swift file and I want to import the frame work and write my code to access DynamoDB in objective C.

I thought I could just import it and start writing on Obj C in my swift file like this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
#import <AWSDynamoDB/AWSDynamoDB.h>

class RateSongsViewController: UIViewController {
```

but I am getting th error:

```
Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
```

What am I doing wrong? and Will I have to create new Objective C files to grab the data from AWS or will I be able because of the header import to write in Objective C in the swift file?

Thanks

Comment: Have you created the Bridging header? Build Settings > Swift Compiler > Objective-C Bridging Header.

Comment: Why cant you try cocoapods?

Comment: Import the header file of the class in the Bridging Header and not in the Swift class. You can access in any .Swift class if you import the class in the Bridging Header.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the project has the Swift header, if not you can create it manually from,

**Build Settings > Swift Compiler > Objective-C Bridging Header**

then import the Objective-C Classes into this Bridging Header file which you want to access in the .Swift classes, that is, now you can access the Objective-C classes in every .Swift class. You do not need to import the class in the .Swift class.

Hope it helps you.